# How to Login user on teamwork without api key on teamwork.com's API using php

Tags: php, teamwork-projects

I am a beginner in php. I want to integrate Teamwork API on my web page. I have already checked how to call different methods of teamwork API and what will be the JSON response of them by using [developer.teamwork.com](http://developer.teamwork.com/account).

Now, I am a bit confused that if I use my API key in the GET request as described [on the api documentation](http://developer.teamwork.com/getrequest2) then the response contains info related to my account. Actually, I want the user to login to his/her teamwork account through my web page and I will retrieve the info regarding their projects on the web page.

So, as far as I understand, I will need to ask for user's API key of his/her teamwork account to display the info on web page. But then it's not a good approach to solve the issue. Is there any other way? Is it possible that user provide their username and password to login and get the account details?

Answer (score 1):

If you use your own API key, then you will get your own information, the api key is connected to the information they have about you.

The key is a certificate about who you are and that you have the right to see the information stored.

As far as i can see teamwork.com have account and billing information in their care, and i would be worried if they shared that information to anyone without special access, such as the API key.

Depending on what you do i would consider the approach you are using, (unless teamwork have some kind of solution for it), making other people share their api key with you could be considered a security breach that could expose sensitive information, in the unfortunate case where you are not able to keep it secure, or where a customer find's you unreliable and prioritize their security over the benefit of your product.